# Producing incorrect `asin(x)` result using a Taylor Series

Tags: c++, math, taylor-series

I am struggling to understand what error I have with my Taylor series `asin(x)` method.

The expansion being implemented is: [image]

Thanks in advance for any recommendations!

***Edit**: removed the `asin_x = -asin_x;` negation per the recommendation from @Sam Varshavchik.  Now it works as it should.

```
Decimal Decimal::get_asin() const {
            
    /*
        Perform a Taylor Series estimation of
        the natural logarithm of this number.
    */

    Decimal one(ONE);
    Decimal two(TWO);

    Decimal x = *this;
    Decimal asin_x = x;

    Decimal asin_x_iter = x;

    Decimal asin_power(3);

    Decimal num_coef(1);
    Decimal den_coef(2);

    Decimal last;

    // Perform the calculation until the last 'last_iter' Decimal
    // is the same as the current calculation 'term'.  

    while (last.get_Integer().get_Whole_Number() != asin_x.get_Integer().get_Whole_Number()) {

        last = asin_x;

        asin_x_iter *= x;
        asin_x_iter *= x;

        asin_x += (one / (den_coef * asin_power)) * (num_coef * asin_x_iter);

        num_coef   *= asin_power;
        asin_power += one;
        den_coef   *= asin_power;
        asin_power += one;
    }

    return asin_x;
}
```

I have checked on this and other StackExchange forums, and have not found clarification.  All of the similar questions I looked at used factorial, power functions, or other build-in functions. The only operators usable here are the standard math operators plus negation.

When running the `asin(x)`, I get the result where `x = 0.2` results in `x = 0.19869011034924140647463691595020`, when it should be `x = 0.20135792079033079145512555221762`.

Comment: And when you used your debugger to run this code, what did you see? This is what a debugger is for and if you don't know how to use it, this is a good opportunity to learn running your program one line at a time in a debugger, monitoring all variables and their values as they change and analysing your program's logic and execution. It should be possible for you to use your debugger to find all simple problems in this and all future programs you write, all by yourself. Do you know how to use a debugger? Knowing how to effectively use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer.

Comment: @Sam, the VS debugger produces no errors, or warnings.  I have also gone through the code line by line.  At this point I think there is an issue with the writing of the Taylor Series in the code example.  The `sin(x)` and the `atan(x)` both work fine.  I am also not finding any errors in the class implementation either.  I'm stumped.  But if you have any suggestions I am all ears.

Comment: There's more to debuggers than showing any errors or warnings. Debuggers also monitor and display the values of all variables, making it easy to observe how they change after executing each line, step by step. One thing that's immediately apparent to me that looks completely wrong: the shown code executes a negation as part of each step, in the loop. Which part of the shown mathematical formula involves changing signs, on every step?

Comment: @StormCrow Why `asin_x = -asin_x;`? I can't see how you get that from the formulae above. If I remove that line and replace `Decimal` with `double` I get the right answer.

Comment: @Sam, your negation observation is the missing link.  Thank you!  This is obviously the case of looking of implementing too many similar series.  The negation is required in both the `sin(x)` and the `atan(x)`.  And regardless of how many times I looked at the code, the reference for the series, etc. I was just not seeing it.

Comment: @John, thanks for the observation!  Of note the implementation isn't using a double, it is using an arbitrarily precise decimal class.   The negation line was an accidental carry over from the `sin(x)` and `atan(x)` implementations which I was blind too.